# Firebase- long time to receive events

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to use firebase on my android project but It took very long time to receive events, at the beginning of the app it took 2sec to connect (this is ok) next step when I need to receive all the data it takes 30sec+-
to start the receive.

this is the function I am using

```
firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
       //this is call 30sec after connection.
        }
      ...

      }
```

I am also run firebase on  another thread:

```
 firebaseConfig.setEventTarget(new EventTarget() {
         ExecutorService executor =   Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        @Override
        public void postEvent(Runnable runnable) {
            executor.execute(runnable);
        }

        @Override
        public void shutdown() {
            executor.shutdown();
        }

        @Override
        public void restart() {

        }
    });

    Firebase.setDefaultConfig(firebaseConfig);
```

Their is any way to improve the time?
Thanks.

Comment: are you sure there is nothing happening between connecting and setting up the event listener? what is the volume of your data? have you tried it without setting a different thread target?

Comment: without the thread this is the same.

Comment: Are you using the old Firebase API ? It looks like from the code but I wanted to double check with you. Have you tried the new java android api ?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: I am using this one.
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
Their is different in the api ?

Comment: 2.5.2 is quite old now. The name of the function have changed a bit, and some of the getters/setters too. When trying to fix a bad behavior it's always better to use the latest sdk if possible to make sure it hasn't been fixed already.
You have a migration guide here: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Comment: I updated to 9.4.0 and the connection time takes sometimes 30 sec. And sometimes it says that expired auth. and sometimes it works.. The main problem of the time not solved.